# Implementing fast CustomEquality and CustomComparison for discriminated union types

Tags: hash, f#, pattern-matching, equality, discriminated-union

For referencing some coordinates with keys I wanted to use discriminated union types because they allow for efficient pattern matching of all sorts.

Consider the follwoing code snipet:

```
[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type Coord = 
| Spot of AssetKey
| Vol of AssetKey * DateTime option 
| Rate of Currency                                   
.....

    member this.sortKey = 
        match this with
        | Spot(key)                               -> (0 , key.toString)
        | Vol(key)                                -> (1 , key.toString)
        | Vol(key, Some(t))                       -> (2 , key.toString + t.ToShortString())
        | Rate(cur)                               -> (3 , cur.toString)
        ......

    interface IComparable with 
        member this.CompareTo(obj) = 
            match obj with 
            | :? Coord as other -> compare this.sortKey other.sortKey
            | _ -> invalidArg "obj" "not a Coord type"

    override this.Equals(obj) = 
            match obj with 
            | :? Coord as other -> this.sortKey = other.sortKey
            | _ -> false

    override this.GetHashCode() = this.sortKey.GetHashCode()
```

I need to enforce a specific sorting ordering. For example Spot < Vol always. I enforce that with the sortKey member function.

The AssetKey is a again very similar discriminated union type:

```
[<StructuralEqualityAttribute; StructuralComparisonAttribute>]
type AssetKey =
| Equity of string
| EquityIndex of string
.....
```

So this all works nicely, but it is slow. As far as I can see it, if the sortKey function is called, the whole key is built again, in particular the toString functions are called again.

One obvious improvement would be to add a caching layer, which is more a hack than a solution.

An further optimization would be to use a hash key on the strings. But here again I would need to add caching, because I need to cache the hash key and I do not want to recalculate it all over.

The performance optimization would be easier if I use a struct or class, but then I loose the flexibility of pattern matching like for example

```
match c with 
| Coord.Vol(ak, _) when ak = assetKey -> true
| _ -> false
```

What would be an alternative approach, which is well performing? In some of my timings 30% and more of the overall performance is lost in the sortKey function.

Thanks for any suggestions and improvements.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple optimization**
One basic optimization that you could easily do is to avoid calling `toString` when you can make a decision based just on the type of `Coord`. Instead of building `sortKey` you could write:

```
// Separate functions that return tag and key, so that we don't
// have to call 'toString' if we can decide based just on the Tag
member this.Tag = 
    match this with 
    | Spot _ -> 0 | Vol(_, None) -> 1 
    | Vol _ -> 2 | Rate _ -> 3
member this.Key = 
    match this with 
    | Spot(key) | Vol(key, None) -> key.toString | Rate cur -> cur.toString
    | Vol(key, Some t) -> key.toString + t.ToShortString())  

interface IComparable with  
    member this.CompareTo(obj) =  
        match obj with  
        | :? Coord as other -> 
            let c = compare this.Tag other.Tag
            // Try comparing based on the tag first - if the tags 
            // are the same, then get Key and compare based on the key
            if c <> 0 then c else compare this.Key other.Key
        | _ -> invalidArg "obj" "not a Coord type"
```

If you wanted to cache the result of `toString`, then you'd need to use some structure that allows you to store local fields. I would probably use an object type (represented either as a class or simple struct).

**Wrapping the type**
In that case, you could still get nice pattern matching using active patterns, but it requires defining an active pattern for every class (which is probably not that bad). Here is an example:

```
// This type will not be used directly - it is an internal implementation
// hidden from the users that will be accessed using active patterns
[<RequiresQualifiedAccess>]
type AssetKeyInternal =       
  | Equity of string       
  | EquityIndex of string  
  override x.ToString() = ...

// Public type with active patterns for pattern matching
type AssetKey(key:AssteKeyInternal) = 
  let str = lazy key.ToString() // Lazily cached string
  member x.Key = str.Value      // Evaluated when accessed for the first time

  member x.Value = key // Returns the internal representation

// Define active patterns working over AssetKey type
let (|Equity|EquityIndex|) (k:AssetKey) =
  match k.Value with
  | AssetKeyInternal.Equity(e) -> Equity(e)
  | AssetKeyInternal.EquityIndex(e) -> EquityIndex(e)
```

Given a value of type `AssetKey`, you can now write `k.Key` to get the cached string representation and you can pattern match on it using the active patterns:

```
match k with 
| Equity k -> ...
| EquityIndex i -> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider doing something like

```
type CoordRepr =
| Spot of AssetKey 
| Vol of AssetKey * DateTime option  
| Rate of Currency              

let sortKey = function
| Spot(key) -> 1,key.ToString()
| Vol(key,None) -> 2,key.ToString()
| Vol(key,Some(v)) -> 2,key.ToString() + v.ToShortDateString()
| Rate(key) -> 3,key.ToString()

type Coord(repr) =
    let sortKey = sortKey repr
    member __.Repr = repr
    member __.SortKey = sortKey
    override __.Equals(that) =
        match that with
        | :? Coord as c -> sortKey = c.SortKey
        | _ -> false
    override __.GetHashCode() = sortKey.GetHashCode()
    interface System.IComparable with
        member __.CompareTo(that) =
            match that with
            | :? Coord as c -> compare sortKey c.SortKey
            | _ -> failwith "invalidArg"

let Spot k = Coord(Spot k)
let Vol(k,v) = Coord(Vol(k,v))
let Rate(k) = Coord(Rate(k))

let (|Spot|Vol|Rate|) (c:Coord) =
    match c.Repr with
    | Spot k -> Spot k
    | Vol(k,v) -> Vol(k,v)
    | Rate k -> Rate k
```

and then using a signature file to hide `CoordRepr`, `Coord`'s constructor, `sortKey`, etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. I implemented the first version and it is about 100 times faster. Here is my implementation: